# How to connect iPad and iPhone UI XIB elements to same UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, connection, viewcontroller

this may be a noob question, but I'm new to iOS programming and I didn't find an answer to my question elsewhere...

**Following issue**: I am programming a universal app for iPad and iPhone using IB and storyboards. The app is already set up correctly and I have an iPhone and iPad storyboard in my project and both are connected to the right (same) view controller as owner.

So far, so good...

My iPhone app is close to completion and I now want to add the iPad UI, which, apart from the layout and maybe some rearrangement of buttons and views to make use of the larger display, will have the same elements and functionality.

**Now here's my problem**: when I DragDrop my iPad UI element (e.g. a UILabel) to the view controller to connect it I (obviously) can't use the same name...because the iPhone one is already there.
If the item is called 'myTextField' on iPhone I'll have to call it e.g. 'myTextFieldiPad' for the iPad, which means I'll have to branch out every time I want to access the text field depending on the platform. Analogous for IBActions.

**In a nutshell**: same view controller, two practically identical XIB files for iPad and iPhone with identical UI elements, how?

Am I overlooking something?

Help to point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated...

Beschi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create new properties using drag and drop.
You can connect controls from different xibs to the same property on your view controller using drag and drop, instead.

What I mean is, create your properties using drag & drop from iPhone's xib, and then connect your iPad xib controls to the SAME properties you created from your iPhone's xib.

Answer (score -1):

Try create two classes which are children of your BaseViewController. First controller has name iPhoneViewController: BaseViewController, second - iPadViewController: BaseViewController. In IB for first (iPhone) xib you need connect first class. For second - second class. After that where you create viewcontroller you need check idiome. For iPhone create object of iPhoneViewController and  for iPad - second.